# Is it possible to use paging library with MVP architecture in android?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-mvp, android-mvvm

I want to use **paging library** in my application, I have seen multiple sample they all are using view modal component with MVVM architecture, But most of the part of my application is in MVP architecture and I don't want to use MVVM, So is there any way to implement pagination with **paging library with MVP architecture**?

Comment: You can use any component in any architecture. Just read samples and guides to understand what is mvvm and mvp. After that look at the paging library and merge them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can initiate Datasource Factory and implement methods in Presenter like

```
private void initData(String id) {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    factory = new EvaluationDataSourceFactory(compositeDisposable, api, id);

    networkState = Transformations.switchMap(factory.getDataSource(), source -> {
                Timber.d("network status get");
                return source.getNetworkState();
            }
    );

    PagedList.Config pagedListConfig =
            (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                    .setInitialLoadSizeHint(5)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                    .setPageSize(5).build();

    error = Transformations.switchMap(factory.getDataSource(), source -> {
        return source.getError();
    });

    assessments = (new LivePagedListBuilder(factory, pagedListConfig)).setFetchExecutor(executor).build();
}

public void getAssessments(String id) {
    initData(id);
}
```

Then, you can call presenter method from your activity or fragment like

```
presenter.getAssessments(id);
```

It worked for me.